# How to group by then sum within same column value?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to use Pandas (Python3) like SQL. I have a following table.

```
df1
name, score
Tom, 95
Jane, 88
Tom, 30
Lisa, 50
Kyle, 78
Jane, 70
```

What I'm expecting is to group by name and sum score value if name column has same name, then order by score. Hence,

```
df1
name, score
Jane, 158
Tom, 125
Kyle, 78
Lisa, 50
```

Tom and Jane are aggregated and scores are added together per each value. It's like the SQL below.

```
SELECT name, SUM (score) OVER (PARTITION BY name) as _score
FROM ....
WHERE ....
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY _score DESC
```

I tried following but did not work.

```
df1.sort_values(by=['name'],ascending=False).sum()
```

How can I do this in Pandas?

Comment: use df1.groupby('name').sum

Comment: df.groupby('name')['score'].sum().sort_values(ascending = False)

Answer (score 0):

```py
df_1 = {'name': ['tom', 'jane', 'tom', 'lisa', 'kyle', 'jane'],
        'score': [95, 88, 30, 50, 78, 70]}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(df_1)

print(df_1.groupby(['name']).sum().sort_values('score', ascending=False))
```